# Untracked files error when replacing hard coded directory with git submodule

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

I have a git repository with a directory under lib/some_module.

All the files in sub_module are part of the main git repository.

While working on branch B, I deleted everything in some_module, and pulled it from the some_module git. So, now some_module is a submodule of the main repository, but it sits in the same place - lib/some_module.

I added the path to .gitmodules, and ran `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`.
I'm now trying to switch back to main branch, and getting this error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        lib/some_module/.gitignore
        lib/some_module/file1
        ...
```

I obviously don't want to delete these files, as they're now part of the submodule.
What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a bit of a problem.  There's no solution that is both simple *and* good (not yet, anyway).  This is also one of the many reasons that some refer to Git submodules as *sob* -modules.

You *must* remove the files in order to check out that particular commit.  Afterward, you can remove the files *again*, add and commit the result, and add the same submodule back to get the files back.  This is a pain, but it's a one-time pain, except for the fact that the one time repeats in the future if and when it repeats (there's no really good way to summarize this; see the long explanation below).

## Long: what's going on

A Git *repository* is, to a first approximation, simply a collection of *commits*.  It's not about files, though commits contain files; it's not about branches, though branch names help us find commits.  It's all about the *commits*.

Each commit is:

- Numbered.  The unique number for a commit is its *hash ID*.  This number is unique to this commit—not just this commit *in this repository*, but to this commit *in every repository*.  Every Git repository that has this hash ID, has this commit in it; every Git repository that lacks this hash ID, lacks this commit.  That is, the hash ID is a Globally Unique ID (GUID) or Universally Unique ID (UUID).  This is how two Git repositories, when they get together to exchange commits, can tell which one has which commits.  They don't look at the *contents* of the commits at this point, just the IDs: those are unique, so from the IDs alone, they can tell.
- Read-only: no part of any commit can ever be changed.  (This is necessary for the hash IDs to work, since Git itself is distributed.  If you could change a commit, two Gits could get together, exchange a commit and share its hash ID, and then one Git could change the commit so that it doesn't match the other Git repository's copy, and that's not allowed.)
- A container with two parts:

  - There is a snapshot of all files.  The files are stored in a compressed and de-duplicated fashion.  Only Git can even *read* these files, and nothing at all can write them, once they've been written out (because they have the same kind of UUID hash IDs).
  - There is some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself: who made it, when, and why (the log message), for instance.  The metadata include a list of *previous* commit hash IDs, usually exactly one entry long.  This list of previous commits provides edges (outgoing *arcs*) that, together with the commits and their hash IDs, form a **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or DAG, which—besides the hash IDs themselves and their magic uniqueness—is what makes Git work.

Because commits are read-only and otherwise useless for getting any actual work done, we must *extract* a commit—with `git checkout` or `git switch`—to work on or with it.  When we do that, Git extracts *all the files in the commit.*<sup>1</sup>  The extracted files go into a working area, which Git calls our *working tree* or *work-tree*.

In general, this all works pretty well,<sup>2</sup> until we introduce submodules.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's ongoing work on *sparse checkouts*, which avoid this, and may eventually be a method for dealing with this submodule problem.  Right now there's no user-oriented way to do it though.

<sup>2</sup>For some definition of "works pretty well", at least.  Many might argue with this.

---

#### Submodules

A Git submodule is simply a *pair* of Git repositories (or grouping of 2 or more) where:

- at least one repository, called the (or a) *superproject*, stores as one of its "files", a reference to a *single commit* **in** another Git repository; and
- at least one repository, called the (or a) *submodule*, has its checked-out files live within the working tree of its superproject.

The superproject stores the name-and-path of the submodule (`path/to/sub`) in each (new) *commit* in the superproject.  This commit contains a pseudo-file entry, which Git calls a *gitlink*, that stores the hash ID to use *in* the submodule.  The superproject *should* also store a file named `.gitmodules`: this file will contain the instructions necessary for Git to run `git clone` to *create* the Git repository that holds the submodule.  **Git does not enforce the existence of this `.gitmodules` file, and once the clone is made, tends not to bother looking at the `.gitmodules` file either, so it's easy to accidentally make a *broken* submodule where the `.gitmodules` file is missing.**

This is especially true at the time you're first creating a submodule, since you will often *have* the submodule repository, because you just *made* the initial submodule repository.  You don't need to *clone* it now, you just need to make some web hosting site *store* it (e.g., create a new repository on GitHub and then use `git push` to send the commits there).  This also leads to a bit of a [chicken-vs-egg problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) since you may not have created the GitHub repository (or whatever) at the time you're supposed to be running `git submodule add` to create the `.gitmodules` file and/or entry.  The solution is to create the web-hosting repository so that you know for sure its URL, so that you can then run `git submodule add`; you can do the `git submodule add` even though there is nothing to clone yet, because you already *have* the clone, and Git isn't going to try to clone it, or even check the URL you're putting in.  Again, Git doesn't bother looking.  Just make sure you get it right, and you're fine.

#### Where things go wrong

In this particular case, you have some existing commits in which `lib/some_module/` is the prefix of a bunch of existing files *in* those commits.  That means that every time you check out (or switch to) one of those existing commits, Git must *extract all those files*.

Those files live in `lib/some_module/some_file.ext`, for one example.  But currently, `lib/some_module` is your *submodule's working tree*.  So `lib/some_module/some_file.ext` is a file that is checked out from a commit *in* the `lib/some_module/` repository.  It's *not* a file in the superproject.  It's there in the superproject's working tree, so it is by definition an *untracked file*, and it would indeed be overwritten.

In other words, Git won't check out the old commit because the submodule is in the way.  The solution is simple: move or remove the submodule.  It is a clone, and as long as it's a clone in which all of its files can be obtained by re-cloning, it's safe to remove it entirely.<sup>3</sup>

Maybe some of its files *aren't* safe though.  In this case, you have alternatives:

- Commit those files (in the submodule).  Now they're committed.  Make sure to `git push` the new commit, so that it's available.  Remember that the *superproject* repository *records the correct submodule commit* and you've just made a *new* submodule commit, so go to the superproject and `git add` the submodule and commit (and push if needed) to record the new commit hash ID in the superproject!
- Save everything somewhere.  Move the entire sub-tree (with your regular OS "move a tree of files" operation) so that they're all safely out of the way of the superproject, so that running Git commands *in* the superproject have no submodule files that they can wreck.  Having moved the files out of the way, there's now no submodule at all, and it's safe to check out one of those old commits.

You can use both of these techniques (belt-and-suspenders / [belt-and-braces](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/a-belt-and-braces-approach)), if you like.  The point here is to do what's easy to do in a single repository: make sure the files can be recovered, if you do something that overwrites or removes them.  With a single repository, `git status` tells you this; with a submodule, you have to run `git status` *in the submodule* to find out.<sup>4</sup>

**Remember that every time you make a new commit *in* the submodule, you must update the *gitlink* in the superproject.**  The normal action for the superproject Git is to enter each submodule and use a detached-HEAD style `git checkout` or `git switch` to make the *submodule* Git *check out* the commit whose hash ID is *recorded in the superproject*.  So you have to update the superproject, to record the new hash ID.

(In general, you need to do this even when using the fancy update modes, in which you have the superproject run two Git commands: `git fetch`, and then `git merge` or `git rebase`, within the submodule.  These fancy modes are tricky, and because they work on/within the detached HEAD, it gets kind of squirrelly.  You can force the submodule to have an *attached* HEAD by entering the submodule and using `git switch`, which makes it less squirrelly—more like running `git pull` would be—but it's still complicated and hairy: *sob* -modules.)

---

<sup>3</sup>If you're not *sure* whether all of its files can be obtained by re-cloning, just assume that they *can't* and use one of the alternatives.

<sup>4</sup>Note that `git status` in the superproject actually does this for you, optionally, and summarizes it, so you can study [the `git status` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) and make sure it's configured the way you would like.  There is also `git submodule status` from the superproject.